# Can't access build configuration manager or build configurations in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xna, xna-4.0

## Full Story

Typically, when I install Visual C# 2010 Express, the first thing that I do is switch to Expert Settings.  That gives me access to build configurations, and the respective manager.  This most recent installation seems to be misbehaving.

The first project that I created was an XNA 4.0 (Refresh) project.  I imported some old code, switched to Expert Settings, and confirmed that I was able to access both the build configuration manager and the build configuration toolbar.  However, when I opened the project properties and switched to the Build tab, the normal Configuration and Platform dropdowns were nowhere to be found.  Additionally, the Release settings were clearly in use, even though Debug was selected as active in the toolbar/manager.

I tried everything from restarting Visual Studio to manually editing the .csproj XML--which, by the way, marked Debug as the active configuration: not Release.  Interestingly, no matter what the order of the build configurations, if Release was present, that would be the configuration *actually* active in project properties (not selected from the dropdown in the toolbar).  Remember, the dropdowns that usually appear on the project properties pages aren't present, for some reason.

Having no luck, I created two fresh projects in a separate solution: a console application and a WinForms application.  This time, the build configuration manager wasn't even present in the Build menu, and the dropdowns in the toolbar were disabled, as if I didn't even have a solution open.

I've searched and searched, but I cannot find an explanation--or a solution--for this behavior.

Note: I do have access to Visual Studio 2010 through MSDN, so upgrading is a viable solution, if necessary.

## tl;dr

Yes, I've switched to Expert Settings.

- Windows 8 Pro, up-to-date
- Fresh-ish Visual C# 2010 Express installation
- XNA 4.0 Refresh

### Problems

1. New XNA project:

   - Switching build configurations has no effect on actual configuration; it is always stuck on Release, despite saying otherwise.
   - In project properties -> Build, dropdowns for build configuration/platform aren't present.
2. New console/WinForms project:

   - Build Configuration Manager isn't in Build menu.
   - Build configuration toolbar has dropdowns disabled, and nothing is selected.

### Already Attempted

- Delete Release configuration
  Effect: Switches to Debug
- Recreate Release configuration
  Effect: Switches to Debug upon deletion, then back to Release upon recreation
- Fiddle with .csproj XML in text editor
  Effect: None; looked fine to begin with
- Recreate all configurations
  Effect: Always lands on Release
- Restart Visual C# Express 2010
  Effect: None
- Fiddle with settings
  Effect: None
- Reload project
  Effect: None

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open menu: `Tools` -> `Options`...
2. Select `Projects and Solutions`
3. Check `Show advanced build configurations`

I don't recall needing to enable this in the past, though I did always have to switch to Expert Settings.  Then again, I've been using Visual Studio 2012 for a while now, so I might just have forgotten.  I also rarely used Express, so this might be a discrepancy between Express and full versions.

Comment: This is strange, but this solution (which I know works) is not working for me. I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2010 with XNA 4.0, installed on a fresh Windows 10 Pro install. I will post here if I figure it out.

Comment: Here is the solution to my issue above: If you're using an Express version of VS, turn on the Expert Settings (Tools->Settings->Expert Settings). Then the solution here works.